# Are there any Synagogues or Rabbis available in Pakistan?

Tags: rabbis, product-recommendation, geography, chinuch-education, current-events

There was once a very thriving Jewish community available in Pakistan. There was a Synagogue in the port city of Karachi as well till 1985.

What is the current situation now? What if someone would like to meet a Rabbi to learn about Judaism in Pakistan?

Comment: This link might be of help. Not sure:  http://jewishrefugees.blogspot.com/2005/09/surprise-there-are-still-jews-in.html

Comment: I very well aware of that link. Thanks anyway. What i am looking for is an expert Rabbi or an established Synagogue in Pakistan.

Comment: Islamic goverments tend not to be fond of rabbis but if you go to India you will find some

Comment: @simchashatorah I know that as well. There are a lot of Jews still residing in Mumbai.

Comment: @Maxood If you scroll down to the bottom of the comments in the link I provided, it seems that there is somebody else who might be looking for the Jewish community and might have found some of the people. Perhaps they can help you?

Comment: @simchashatorah Please listen to this interview of a Rabbi in Yemen, an arab country which is predominatly muslim. There are still Jews living in Yemen and it will remain there homeland: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8xoLF5ZYJy0

Comment: actually NO!! since the so called Arab spring All of the community is held up in a Hotel under the protection of the current President who is today being replaced partly because of his support of the Jews after one rabbi was Murdered and the President insisted that it go to court because a Jew getting killed would not he got the death penalty but suddenly the Murderer escaped from prison and was never found as the revolution went on

Comment: you choose a topic which I happen to know a bit about but with the exception of the president no one is fond of the Jews in Yemen no Tunisia until the burning of the Shul maybe and Morocco the king is but he is the exception to the rule as is Bahrain where there is a Jewish women in their parliament

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/vjw/Pakistan.html) site:

> Magen Shalome, built by Shalome Solomon Umerdekar and his son Gershone
>   Solomon, Karachi’s last synagogue, was demolished in the 1980s to make
>   way for a shopping plaza. Most of the Karachi Jews now live in Ramle,
>   Israel, and built a synagogue they named Magen Shalome. Some Jewish
>   families do remain, but they prefer to pass themselves off as Parsis
>   due to the intolerance for Jews in Muslim Pakistan. Their number is
>   estimated to be around 200 persons.

According to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Jews_in_Pakistan):

> The original Ark and podium were stored by a non-Jew in Karachi; a
>   Torah scroll case was taken by an American Jewess to the US. In 2004
>   she donated synagogue registers covering the period 1961-1976 to the
>   Ben-Zvi Institute Library in Jerusalem. Two silver Kiddush glasses
>   from Magain Shalome were donated to the Museum of the International
>   Synagogue at John F. Kennedy Airport in New York in honour of the
>   memory of the late president.

Comment: Here is a great link of the memorable Synagogue here: http://haroonhaider.com/2010/09/13/magen-shalom-the-last-synagogue-in-pakistan/. I really wish if i can meet some Jewish families in Karachi. :)

Comment: Is there a pic somewhere of the two glasses in JFK?

Comment: Parsis follow Zoroastrianism ... that's interesting, may a Jew pose as a Zoroastrian to avoid persecution ...